# How can we enumerate in that way?

Tags: enumerate

I want to have the following:

```
(αʹ) .... 
(βʹ) 
(βʹ.1) .... 
(βʹ.2) ....
```

The

```
(αʹ) .... 
(βʹ)
```

we get them using the following

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)] 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

How do we get the

```
(βʹ.1) .... 
(βʹ.2) ....
```

?

---

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{enumerate} 

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 

\graphicspath{ {images/} } 

\usepackage{enumitem} 

\usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\greekalpha}[1]{\c@greekalpha{#1}}
\newcommand{\c@greekalpha}[1]{%
  {%
    \boldmath
    \ifcase\number\value{#1} %
    \or
    \textalpha
    \or
    \textbeta
    \or
    \textgamma 
    \or 
    \textdelta 
    \or 
    \textsigma\texttau
    \or 
    \textzeta
    \fi
  }%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\greekalpha}{\c@greekalpha}{5}
\makeatother


\providecommand{\textdexiakeraia}{some font I don't have}

\title{ } 
\author{ } 
\date{ } 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)] 
\item .....
\item 
\begin{enumerate}[($\beta'.1$)]
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{First} 
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Second} 
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Third} 
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Fourth}  
\end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

(To be honest I don't need all of the packages I have written.)

Comment: You should make a small, complete example instead of letting everyone guess if you use enumerate or enumitem and how you manage to get alpha and beta in your list with the command `\alph`.

Comment: I added my whole code. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Totally irrelevant, but you are missing epsilon from your greek counter definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading both `enumerate` and `enumitem` is wrong; just load the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item 'alfa
\item b'hta
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph{enumi}.\arabic*)]
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{First}
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Second}
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Third}
\item \foreignlanguage{english}{Fourth}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ok!! Now it works!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[($\beta'.1$)]
\item First 
\item Second 
\item Third 
\item Fourth 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't get the desired result and there is also an error... Do you maybe mean `\begin{enumerate}[label=($\beta'.1$)]` ? 
Only β.1 is appeared. How do we get also β.2 ?

Comment: @MaryStar: Copy and paste the given code exactly and compile. Perhaps you have made a mistake. Check if you have loaded the enumerate package in the preamble.

Comment: Do you use also sharelatex? I get the following errors: [http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4541/ym87ld57_png.htm ] and [http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4541/5skjvkol_png.htm ] and the output is the following: [http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4541/plkqn53l_png.htm ]

Comment: @MaryStar: Those links point to errors but I dont know whether you have used \usepackage{enumerate} before \begin{document}.

Comment: I used it but I used also `\usepackage{enumitem}` that's why there was an error. Now I deleted this comment and now it is ok. But now I cannot use the command `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` for the `(αʹ) .... 
(βʹ) ` . What could I do now?

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

- Using the `label*` option in you second list

  ```
      \documentclass{article}
      \usepackage{enumitem}
  \begin{document}
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*] 
          \item foo 
          \item bar 
          \begin{enumerate}[label*= .\arabic*]
              \item alice 
              \item bob
          \end{enumerate} 
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Using the `\theenumi` counter with `label` option

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
      \usepackage{enumitem}
  \begin{document}
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*] 
          \item foo 
          \item bar 
          \begin{enumerate}[label= \theenumi.\arabic*]
              \item alice 
              \item bob
          \end{enumerate} 
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
  ```

However, things gets a bit more tricky when you format the first label, since `\theenumi` keeps this formating (e.g. using brackets).

Comment: So, is it better not use brackets at the first label?